# How to Stop animation when numbers hit 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wanting to know how to stop the animation when new text is shown. Everything works but when new text is shown it keeps animating.

```
$(function(){

var note = $('#note'),
    ts = new Date(2013, 11, 11),
    newYear = true;

if((new Date()) > ts){
    // The new year is here! Count towards something else.
    // Notice the *1000 at the end - time must be in milliseconds
    ts = (new Date()).getTime() + 00*00*00*00*0000;
    newYear = false;
}

$('#countdown').countdown({
    timestamp   : ts,
    callback    : function(days, hours, minutes, seconds){

        var message = "";

        message += days + " day" + ( days==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
        message += hours + " hour" + ( hours==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
        message += minutes + " minute" + ( minutes==1 ? '':'s' ) + " and ";
        message += seconds + " second" + ( seconds==1 ? '':'s' ) + " <br />";



        note.html(message);

        if(days==0 && hours==0 && minutes==0 && seconds==0)
          {
             $("#events").animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000, function () {
                $(this).text('Jamboree Has Started!!!!!!');
           }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000);                 
       }

    }
});
});
```

I know the reason why it keeps animating is because all numbers stay at 0 once they all hit 0. Is there maybe another way I could get this to work, show new text with out it annimaing once all numbers hit 0?

Comment: which is the countdown plugin used

Answer (score 0):

You want the animation to be occurred only once.  So you can make use of [**`.one()`**](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

```
 $("#events").one(function () {
     $(this).animate({'opacity': 0}, 1000, function () {
            $(this).text('Jamboree Has Started!!!!!!');
     }).animate({'opacity': 1}, 1000);
 });
```

However For stopping animation, [**`.stop()`**](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) can be used.  In your case it is not needed.

Comment: Tried that and the original text stays showing. Have tried .stop() but make the whole countdown timer disappear except for the Text. Also tried removing }) at the end and messed up countdown.

Comment: Never used jsfiddle before. Looked at it and really not sure how to include all files needed to make countdown work. Have one folder named assets with 4 folders inside.

Comment: @user1236784 Ohh.  ok.  can you tell about the count down plugin?  url to access this plugin?

Comment: This is the tutorial for the plugin. http://tutorialzine.com/2011/12/countdown-jquery/